# Create command thowrs ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number exception

Tags: c#, plsql, oracle11g

I am working on fixing an SQL Injection flaw reported by some tool.
Our application was reading Oracle queries from an xml. The query is shown below...

```
<CommandText>create user &amp;USERNAME identified externally</CommandText>
```

In the program, the query **was** modified as follows...

```
create user User_05 identified externally
```

I was asked to add parameter statements to avoid SQL Injection. So I did similar thing as shown  below...

```
OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "create user :USERNAME identified externally";
string attrName = "USERNAME";
string valueToBePut = "User_05";
command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(attrName, valueToBePut));
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

and when I tried to execute the query. It is failing with the following exception:

```
{"ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number"}
```

Can anyone help me on this. What I might be doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: No, parameters cannot be used to represent columns or tables names. (and this is true not just for Oracle)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So, you mean to say that, we can't parametrize these kind of queries?

Comment: Yes, I created a sample application to check this. You are correct, we can't parametrize the column or table names. What I need to do in order to fix this? Any Idea?

Comment: I am not an expert about Oracle, but you should search something like the QUOTENAME function available in SQL Server. I suppose that Oracle has something similar. However also this is not a complete workaround for Sql Injection and, perhaps, for your case a little code effort on your part to whitelist the input could be written.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent someone exploiting this code, you should check if the entered values are save. Oracle provides the DBMS_ASSERT package to do this for you.

What I would do is create a stored procedure which accepts the username an argument. This stored procedure would create the database user for you.
The stored procedure would verify the argument if there is no SQL Injection using

```
DBMS_ASSERT.QUALIFIED_SQL_NAME ();
```

Your code would bind the input to calling that stored procedure.

Check out the DBMS_ASSERT package http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_assert.htm#ARPLS65375

What I don't understand is why you would want to create users on the fly...